# Close Notification After Clicking on It

Tags: java, android, android-intent, android-notifications

I created a notification but once I click on it it does not remove! I even tried `notification.setAutoCancel(true)` and `notification.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL`

Here is my code:

```
notification.setSmallIcon(R.drawable.message64);
Uri uri= RingtoneManager.getDefaultUri(RingtoneManager.TYPE_NOTIFICATION);
notification.setSound(uri);

Resources resources = getApplicationContext().getResources(),
            systemResources = Resources.getSystem();
notification.setTicker("Notification");
notification.setContentTitle("Nouveau message");
notification.setContentText("Vous avez reçu un nouveau message. ");
Intent intent = new Intent(getApplicationContext(), MainActivity.class);
PendingIntent pendingIntent = PendingIntent.getActivity(getApplicationContext(),0,intent,PendingIntent.FLAG_UPDATE_CURRENT);
notification.setContentIntent(pendingIntent);

NotificationManager nm = (NotificationManager) getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE);
notification.getNotification().flags |= Notification.FLAG_AUTO_CANCEL;
nm.notify(uniqueID,notification.build());
```

It is working well but it still doesn't remove it when I click on it.

Comment: `notification.setAutoCancel(true);`

Comment: i used it already dude.

Comment: try my edited answer just replace your NotificationManager

Comment: replace it? how dude please

Comment: look at my answer just copy paste it then try. Just change your `your_unique_id`

Answer (score 0):

```
 NotificationCompat.Builder builder = new NotificationCompat.Builder(this)
            .setWhen(System.currentTimeMillis())
            .setLargeIcon(BitmapFactory.decodeResource(getResources(),
                    R.mipmap.ic_launcher))
            .setContentTitle(getString(R.string.app_name))
            .setAutoCancel(true)

            .setContentText("Test")



    getManager().notify(ID, builder.build());
```

Using `setAutoCancel(true)` does notification clear on click